# Query to get name from a table with 2 ID columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 tables. The first has a structure like

```
id (int)
parent_id (int)
category_name (varchar)
```

The second has a structure like:

```
id (int)
old_category (int)
new_category (int)
```

I want to make a query to pull the old category and new category names all in one query for the parents. That is, I want to get the name of the old parent, then get the name of the new parent. The second table contains a historical list of all the parent ID changes made in the first table. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Come on, this is simple join...

Comment: @barti_ddu: everyone starts somewhere.  Or were you born with simple joins coded into your DNA?

Comment: @barti_ddu so what?  Many people have beginner questions.  It just adds to the SO pages for seo.

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT old_cat.category_name, new_cat.category_name
     FROM join_table
LEFT JOIN category_table as old_cat
       ON old_cat.id = join_table.old_category
LEFT JOIN category_table as new_cat
       ON new_cat.id = join_table.new_category;
```

If you've managed to get this far, it's time to stop coding and start learning [`MySQL JOIN Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html).

Answer (score 0):

I will take a guess at what you meant:

**tblOne**

id

cat_name

**tblTwo**

id

tblOneId (old_cat) int

new_cat int

```
select * from tblOne t1, tblTwo t2 Where t1.id = t2.tblOneId
```

Comment: I want to get the name of the old category and the new category. The second table contains the historical records of the category name changes. Meaning, 1 category moved from parent to another (I am updating this in my original post, this is not clear).

Comment: is old_category the id from the first table?

Answer (score 0):

Join them?

```
select * from table1
  join table2 j1 on table2.id = table1.old_category
  join table2 j2 on table2.id = table1.new_category
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.old_category,
  oc.category_name as old_category_name,
  t.new_catevory,
  nc.category_name as new_category_name
FROM
  table1 t
  INNER JOIN table2 oc on oc.id = t.old_category
  INNER JOIN table2 nc on nc.id = t.new_category
```

I would seriously consider some modifications in column names, btw. To start: why don't the categories in table2 have an id postfix?