# How to retrieve data for two foreign key ID and one same base table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, select, query-optimization

I have a table for messages of my application which contains 2 user ID per each row as below:

**tbl_messages:**

| id | message_title | owner_user_id | recipient_user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Message 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | Message 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | Message 3 | 4 | 9 |

User IDs are foreign keys of this table in my MySQL database. The main table is like this:

**tbl_users**

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sarah | Pearson |
| 2 | John | Smith |
| 3 | Mery | Taylor |

I know how can I retrieve the `first_name` and `last_name` of a person by using a JOIN like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
    FROM tbl_messages m
    JOIN tbl_users u  ON u.id = m.owner_user_id;
```

But I wonder to know how can I do it for both `owner_user_id` and `recipient_user_id` at one SQL command? Is it possible?
If the answer is no, I have to read the message row data, and then query 2 other statements to retrieve the data for those two fields which makes the process more heavy while working with thousands of records in table of users. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query to get name from a table with 2 ID columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308644/query-to-get-name-from-a-table-with-2-id-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use alias to determine which data is from each user. Try:

```
SELECT owner.first_name, 
       owner.last_name, 
       recipient.first_name, 
       recipient.last_name 
FROM tbl_messages AS msgs 
JOIN tbl_users AS owner 
  ON owner.id = msgs.owner_user_id 
JOIN tbl_users AS recipient 
  ON recipient.id = msgs.recipient_user_id;
```

Comment: To explain further a table or view can be joined multiple times in a `SELECT` query. When doing so different aliases need to be added for each "table instance". This allows the predictes and column list to specify exactly where it's coming from.

Comment: I did not know it is possible. Thank you @lucas. You helped me to decrease the process time on my heavy database.