# Left Join showing multiple values from the joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Having this SQL:

```sql
create table Team(id integer, attacker int, midfield int, defender int);
insert into Team(id, attacker, midfield, defender) values(1, 50, 51, 51);
insert into Team(id, attacker, midfield, defender) values(2, 50, NULL, 55);
insert into Team(id, attacker, midfield, defender) values(12, 50, 53, NULL);


create table Footballer(id integer, name varchar(100));
insert into Footballer(id, name) values (50, "AbbaDude");
insert into Footballer(id, name) values (51, "BravoDude");
insert into Footballer(id, name) values (52, "Charlie");
insert into Footballer(id, name) values (53, "Dude");
insert into Footballer(id, name) values (54, "Elfonso");
insert into Footballer(id, name) values (55, "Fix");

select t.id, t.attacker, t.midfield, t.defender, f.name from Team t 
left join Footballer f on f.id = t.id
```

I get this:

```
id  attacker    midfield    defender    name
1   50          51          51          NULL
2   50          NULL        55          NULL
12  50          53          NULL        NULL
```

And instead of the numbers (50, 51,55, etc) I want to see the names from table `Footballer`.

```
id  attacker    midfield    defender    
1   AbbaDude    BravoDude   BravoDude   
2   AbbaDude    NULL        Fix         
12  AbbaDude    Dude        NULL
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a MYSQL Self-Join Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284441/how-does-a-mysql-self-join-work)

Comment: Anyway this is a duplicate of the very basic idea of a many:1 join, a duplicate case of which is to get a name from an id, a duplicate case of which involves multiple ids/names, a duplicate case of which involves the same table more than once, eg [Query to get name from a table with 2 ID columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4308644/3404097) PS [How to get matching data from another SQL table for two different columns: Inner Join and/or Union?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27682228/3404097) 
[What is a self join for? (in english)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37384306/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
select t.id, at.name, md.name, df.name 
from Team t 
left join Footballer at on at.id = t.attacker
left join Footballer md on md.id = t.midfield
left join Footballer df on df.id = t.defender
```

Comment: Works, thanks. If there is nothing better than 3 `left-joins`, I will select it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table Footballer three times, so we use aliases to know which join we are referring to. I like to use one or two letter aliases, but a letter which lets you know what you are referring to.
Here a for attacker, m for midfield and d for defender.

> ```
> select
>   t.id,
>   a.name attacker,
>   m.name midfield,
>   d.name defender
> from Team t
> left join Footballer a on t.attacker = a.id
> left join Footballer m on t.midfield = m.id
> left join Footballer d on t.defender = d.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | attacker | midfield  | defender 
> -: | :------- | :-------- | :--------
>  1 | AbbaDude | BravoDude | BravoDude
>  2 | AbbaDude | null      | Fix      
> 12 | AbbaDude | Dude      | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0fd3ca07faaf0bd3bbf22dfdf57e9d90)*

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned below to Hamed, unless there is something better than 3 left-joins, this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need temId value in Footballer table. So,
yo must use this codes:

```
create table Footballer(id integer,teamId integer , name varchar(100))
insert into Footballer(id, name) values (50,[teamId], "AbbaDude");
insert into Footballer(id, name) values (51,,[teamId], "BravoDude");

select t.id, t.attacker, t.midfield, t.defender, f.name from Team t 
left join Footballer f on f.teamId = t.id
```

all codes:

```
create table Team(id integer, attacker int, midfield int, defender int);
insert into Team(id, attacker, midfield, defender) values(1, 50, 51, 51);
insert into Team(id, attacker, midfield, defender) values(2, 50, NULL, 55);
insert into Team(id, attacker, midfield, defender) values(12, 50, 53, NULL);


create table Footballer(id integer,teamID INTEGER, name varchar(100));
insert into Footballer(id,teamID, name) values (50,1, 'AbbaDude');
insert into Footballer(id,teamID, name) values (51,2, 'BravoDude');
insert into Footballer(id,teamID, name) values (52,1, 'Charlie');
insert into Footballer(id,teamID, name) values (53,12, 'Dude');
insert into Footballer(id,teamID, name) values (54,12, 'Elfonso');
insert into Footballer(id,teamID, name) values (55,1, 'Fix');

select t.id, t.attacker, t.midfield, t.defender, f.name from Team t 
left join Footballer f on f.teamID = t.id
```

Comment: Nope, this is not the idea by design.