# Inner join get two name columns with id from other table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have this code

```
SELECT
    home, away, teams.name as home_name, teams.abbreviation as home_abbr, teams.name as away_name, teams.abbreviation as away_abbr
FROM
    games
INNER JOIN
    teams ON games.home = teams.id
WHERE
    games.date >= '2022-01-01'
```

and this result

[image]

I have two tables "games" and "teams". In "games" table have home and away columns. There only wrote id team. In "teams" table have name, abbriviation, icon and other information. I need get home and away teams names and abbriviations with union query from "teams" table. In my situation get only one (home or away) column information

Comment: please share exact sample data and expected result from the sample

Comment: [mre] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help] This is very unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: OK, I spotted a little late that you select `teams.name as home_name`, which is already wrong if you look at the naming. Instead you should select `home.name as home_name, home.abbreviation as home_abbr`.

Comment: @Ronald i have not table home. You wrote home.name.... I have tables games and teams

Comment: Again: "Please clarify via edits, not comments."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to get name from a table with 2 ID columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4308644/3404097)

Comment: After locating a problem via [mre]: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & sometimes limited to titles, but read the help. Google re googling/searching, including in Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: You have made the code complicated. It was easy if you put a field `type` in team table and save away and home in that but in your case you need to use 2 joins or implement with union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you have two values of teams in the "game" you need to "lookup".  This means you need two joins in order to get the different values for home and away.

**Assuming**

- game has `home` and `away` foreign key ID's from `teams` table...
- each game consists of two teams one "home" and one "away"

We simply join from games twice, once for the "home team" data, and once for the "away team" data.  We will need to alias each join "h" (home) "a" (away)
and then update fields to use the correct alias.

**Giving us:**

```
SELECT g.home, g.away, 
       h.name as home_name, h.abbreviation as home_abbr, 
       a.name as away_name, a.abbreviation as away_abbr
FROM games g
INNER JOIN teams h
  ON g.home = h.id
INNER JOIN teams a
  ON g.away = a.id
WHERE g.date >= '2022-01-01'
```

**Note:**
For clarity I aliased all 3 tables and each of the fields in select/join/where

**Outstanding questions**
You said, " need get home and away teams names and abbreviations with union query from "teams" table."

Why is a union needed at all?  Was this how you thought you could get both teams names/abbreviations?  If so this approach doesn't make sense to me as a Join will suffice. unless you're looking for results for a game on different lines: which your example output didn't show.  So i think union is  the wrong approach given desired results.   This isn't to say it couldn't be done with a union and a max and a group by; but it's more work and likely slower than a simple join.

Comment: Yes Union can give same result but First it will return all data of `home` and than `away`

Comment: He can use a type column in team table to make it easy. But depend on his project and requirements

Comment: Honestly I think it doesn't get simpler than joining to the same table twice alias one join for home and one for away.  It's a sound design.  Like flights having arrivals and departures, I don't want to type the data as a flight has 1 departure and 1 arrival.  now if a game had N teams involved then yes a game and type field might make sense but if we know there's always just 2 teams, no need to allow for N team participation.