# Join two tabels - Oracle SQL

Tags: left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables and I would like to join them. Below there are the examples of tables and the result table:

Table A

| ID | PLACE | R_ID | M_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PLACE_1 | 51 | 53 |
| 2 | PLACE_2 | 52 | 54 |

Table B

| S_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 51 | A |
| 52 | B |
| 53 | C |
| 54 | D |

Output Table

| ID | PLACE | R_NAME | M_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PLACE_1 | A | C |
| 2 | PLACE_2 | B | D |

I tried query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    place,
    name as r_name
FROM
    table_a 
    LEFT JOIN table_b ON r_id = s_id
```

Query result

| ID | PLACE | R_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PLACE_1 | A |
| 2 | PLACE_2 | B |

But I don't know how to join next column **m_name**.

Comment: "join them" & "join next column" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS [Query to get name from a table with 2 ID columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4308644/3404097) [How to get matching data from another SQL table for two different columns: Inner Join and/or Union?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27682228/3404097) What is a self join for? (in english)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37384306/3404097)

Comment: (Clearly.) When clear this will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join twice to the same table and use table aliases to distinguish between the two:

```sql
SELECT id,
       place,
       r.name as r_name,
       m.name as m_name
FROM   table_a a
       LEFT JOIN table_b r ON a.r_id = r.s_id
       LEFT JOIN table_b m ON a.m_id = m.s_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table_A (ID, PLACE, R_ID, M_ID) AS
SELECT 1, 'PLACE_1', 51, 53 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'PLACE_2', 52, 54 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table_B (S_ID, NAME) AS
SELECT 51, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 52, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 53, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 54, 'D' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | PLACE | R_NAME | M_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PLACE_1 | A | C |
| 2 | PLACE_2 | B | D |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NzE1HjDm)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
with cte_r as ( 
  SELECT a.ID, a.PLACE, b.NAME
  FROM tableA a
  INNER JOIN tableB b on a.R_ID = b.S_ID
),
cte_m as (
  SELECT a.ID, a.PLACE, b.NAME
  FROM tableA a
  INNER JOIN tableB b on a.M_ID = b.S_ID
)
SELECT r.ID, r.PLACE, r.NAME as R_NAME, m.NAME as M_NAME
FROM cte_r r
LEFT JOIN cte_m m on r.ID = m.ID and r.PLACE = m.PLACE
```

Result :

```
ID  PLACE   R_NAME  M_NAME
1   PLACE_1 A       C
2   PLACE_2 B       D
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tR0rbfkQ)

Answer (score 0):

Also do it using subquery:

```
SELECT a.id,
   a.place,
   (SELECT name FROM table_b r WHERE a.r_id = r.s_id) AS r_name,
   (SELECT name FROM table_b m WHERE a.m_id = m.s_id) AS m_name
FROM table_a a;
```